# How to host 2 webapps on the same server

Tags: ubuntu, apache-virtualhost

I'm currently in the process of configuring 2 third party apps for a game called EVE Online, one of them is Pathfinder and the other is a corporation management app.

for example if I want to access Pathfinder my URL would be `mydomain.com/pathfinder`, but if wanted to access the other app my URL would be `mydomain.com/otherapp`.

Pathfinder is located in the `DocumentRoot` folder (`/var/www/pathfinder`) and the other app should be in the `DocumentRoot` folder aswell (`/var/www/otherapp`)

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName mydomain.com

ServerAdmin admin@bfc.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/pathfinder

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: You would probably get more answers from http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: It seems that you want the default behavior of serving files. Won't this work if you simply use /var/www as your DocumentRoot?

Comment: @Teekin I think I already tried that... Pathfinder has a weird .htaccess file... this kind of stuff is out of my area of expertise

Comment: "Weird" doesn't really tell us much about the problem. :) At any rate, you seem to want the default behavior, so if it doesn't work, there has to be something wrong with it. What's in the .htaccess file? You can try reading it, and looking up online what each sentence in it means. It's a good way to learn some Apache.

Or if it doesn't contain any secret info (like passwords or something), then it would be helpful to post its contents in the question as well. You can edit it.

Answer (score 3):

Create two `VirtualHosts` (it would be good practice to have them in separated files)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pathfinder.dev
    ServerAlias www.pathfinder.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/pathfinder
    <Directory /var/www/pathfinder>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        #... 
    </Directory>
    #...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName otherapp.dev
    ServerAlias www.otherapp.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/otherapp
    <Directory /var/www/otherapp>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        #...
    </Directory>
    #...
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit your hosts file `/etc/hosts` and add these lines:

```
127.0.0.1   pathfinder.dev
127.0.0.1   otherapp.dev
```

Save changes and restart apache server. Open browser and go to your first project `http://pathfinder.dev` and to your second app `http://otherapp.dev`

Comment: like this? 
'<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com/otherapp

ServerAdmin admin@bfc.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/otherapp

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/otherapp>
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>'

Answer (score 0):

You used Alias /pathfinder  /var/www/pathfinder and  Alias /otherapp /var/www/otherapp. You didnt need to use virtualhost.You can browse yourdomain.com/pathfinder and yourdomain.com/otherapp. You can not use virtualhost and Alias on same server.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to configure two different virtual hosts
You may use subdomains to keep them separate or listen on the different ports as it fits you best.

You also may like to use some control panel like [this one](http://serversuit.com), to manage Apache, domains and subdomains if you feel yourself not completely sure about config files.

Regards.